# Haskell: where clause referencing bound variables in lambda

Tags: haskell, where-clause, lambda

I am trying to numerically integrate a function in Haskell using the trapezoidal rule, returning an anti-derivative which takes arguments a, b, for the endpoints of the interval to be integrated.

```
integrate :: (Float -> Float) -> (Float -> Float -> Float)

integrate f
  = \ a b -> d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)
    where
      d = (b - a) / n
      n = 1000
```

In the above, I use

```
n - for the number of subintervals
d - for the width of each subinterval
```

This almost works, except for the bound arguments a,b in the lambda.  I get the
error message:

```
Not in scope: `b'
Not in scope: `a'
```

I can understand that the scope of a,b is restricted to just that lambda expression, but
is there a workaround in Haskell so that I don't have to write (b-a)/n for each occurrence of d in the above?

Comment: TIL: You can't use `where` with lambdas [let vs where](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Let_vs._Where).  See also [where does the `where` clause come in handy in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032183/where-does-the-where-clause-come-in-handy-in-haskell)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied. I did not realize that this problem leads directly to a well-known let vs where discussion. I also want to thank those who suggested that I write the function as:  integrate f a b = ... That's a nice and succinct solution as well.

Answer (score 19):

You're thinking you need to return a function which takes two `Float`s and returns a `Float`, but actually that's no different to taking two extra `Float` arguments in your `integrate` function and using currying (i.e. just don't provide them and the return type will be `Float -> Float -> Float`).

So you can rewrite your function like this

```
integrate :: (Float -> Float) -> Float -> Float -> Float

integrate f a b
  = d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)
    where
      d = (b - a) / n
      n = 1000
```

Or you could use `let ... in` instead of `where`:

```
integrate f
  = \a b ->
      let d = (b - a / n)
          n = 1000
      in d * sum [ f (a + d * k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)
```

Comment: FWIW, Matthew omitted the parentheses in the type signature, but that is not necessary.  You can keep the type signature the same and write the function body in this new way.  The two signatures are *exactly* equivalent.

Comment: Well spotted. I was intending to mention that when I was writing the answer but I must've forgotten.

Comment: Thanks.  Rewriting the function as  integrate f a b = ... is a great solution.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

```
integrate f a b = d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)
    where 
      d = (b - a) / n
      n = 1000
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of work-arounds.

If you don't know any binding syntax except lambda expressions you can do this (which I love the most because of its theoretical beauty, but never use because of its syntactic ugliness):

```
integrate f
  = \a b -> (\d -> d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)) 
             ((b - a) / n)
    where
      n = 1000
```

If you like definitions and only know `where`-syntax you can do this:

```
integrate f = go
  where
    n = 1000
    go a b = d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)
      where
        d = (b - a) / n
```

If you also know `let`-syntax, you can do this:

```
integrate f = 
  \a b -> let d = (b - a) / n 
          in d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)
  where
    n = 1000
```

Finally, if you remember that `a -> (b -> c -> d)` is the same as `a -> b -> c -> d`, you can do the obvious:

```
integrate f a b = d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)
  where
    n = 1000
    d = (b - a) / n
```

Comment: There is another reason not to use the first option: lambdas do not have let polymorphism.

Comment: Thank you.  The let option is probably the simplest workaround for my where bound-variable problem.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about "go"? I've tried to look it up, but it's very difficult to find any information about "go" in Haskell, because search engines confuse it with the usual English word "go", and "go" does not appear in most book indices.

Comment: @Bylextor, `go` is just an arbitrary name, like `foo`. You use that for a helper function when you run out of imagination. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on where:

```
integrate f = \a b -> case () of
    () ->  d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)
           where 
               d = (b - a) / n
               n = 1000
```

Looks pretty nice, does it not?
To make the case look a bit more motivated:

```
integrate f = \a b -> case (f a + f b) of
    fs ->  d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * fs
           where 
               d = (b - a) / n
               n = 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
integrate f a b = d * sum [ f (a + d*k) | k <- [0..n] ] - d/2.0 * (f a + f b)
    where
      d = (b - a) / n
      n = 1000
```