# Difference between where bindings, let bindings and the single assignment operator (<-)

Tags: haskell, syntax, binding, let, do-notation

I do not understand the difference between the three syntaxes:

- `where    a = f (b)`
- `do    a <- f (b)`
- `do    let a = f (b)`

I do understand somehow though that `a <- f(b)` is different from the other two, in most cases where I tried all three worked. Also I read somewhere on the net that per block you should try to get along with one let binding only in order to be "idiomatic". But I never seem to manage.

How do I decide what to use?

Comment: You must have tried wrong. I can think of almost no scenario where changing `a <- f b` to `let a = f b` (or vice versa) wouldn't break your code. That is assuming you're actually using `a` afterwards.

Comment: @sepp2k yes, but you can easily refactor your code to make it work. Same thing with let and where, "minor" refactoring is required. As I mentioned, I am aware that the single assignment operator is somehow different. Still I like to know what the difference is.

Comment: No, you can't. If `f b` has a non-monadic type `a <- f b` will simply not compile. There's no refactoring you can do to make it compile (unless you count stuffing a `return` in there to be refactoring...). If `f b` does have a monadic type, `let a = f b` will cause `a` to have the same type. This will almost certainly break the code using `a`.

Comment: @sepp2k Not sure if I can "compete" with you on this, but isn't it if I stay in the same monad it should not matter?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you have multiple `<-`s inside a do-block, their respective right operands must be in the same monad. But that has nothing to do with `let`.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4362328/596361

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`let foo = bar in ...` simply defines `foo` to be the exact same thing as `bar` within the context of `...`; you could simply use textual substitution to replace all uses of `foo` in `...` with `(bar)` and get the exact same result.

`where` clauses are similar to `let...in` expressions, but go at the end of a function clause, instead of being an expression. For instance,

```
foo x
    | p1 = ... y ...
    | p2 = ... y ...
  where
    y = ...
```

There is no way to rewrite this with `let...in` without changing the guards into `if...then...else`s. Often, `where` clauses are used over `let...in` clauses purely for reasons of style.

The bind operator is something different entirely. It's used in `do` notation to "extract" a value from a monadic computation. That is, if `foo` has the type `m a`, then after `x <- foo`, `x` has the type `a`. All the other "binding" forms just define names, but `<-` is used for *binding* a computation's result to a name from within a monad. `<-` can only be used inside a `do` block, so it's exclusively used to build up a larger computation in the same monad as the action you're binding the result of.

`let foo = bar` in `do` notation is just a convenience; you can rewrite:

```
do let foo = bar
   ...
```

as

```
let foo = bar
in do ...
```

but that gets messy when you have a lot of such bindings, as the `do` blocks get nested deeper and deeper.

I don't know what the advice you mentioned is talking about; you can define multiple variables in a `let...in` block just fine, and

```
let foo = ...
    bar ...
in ...
```

is more idiomatic than

```
let foo = ...
in let bar = ...
   in ...
```