# Using variable from outer scope in where in do block

Tags: haskell, scope, where-clause, do-notation

I'm trying to use the variable defined in the outer scope within an action defined in `do` block using `where`:

```hs
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
    outerVar <- return "a"
    doSomething
    where
        doSomething :: IO String
        doSomething = putStrLn ("outerVar: " ++ outerVar)
```

Given this snippet, I'm trying to understand why does the compiler return the following error:

```
error: Variable not in scope: outerVar :: [Char]
  |
9 |         doSomething = putStrLn ("outerVar: " ++ outerVar)
  |
```

Based on my understanding - `doSomething` function should create some kind of a "closure" to contain the value of `outerVar` (which I've just found out is called a [free variable](https://wiki.haskell.org/Free_variable)), but that doesn't happen.

I've spent quite a lot of time trying to figure out why exactly does this error happen. I'm quite embarassed as, even for me as a Haskell newbie, it seems almost like a basic concept that should be obvious but it isn't - hopefully I'm wrong. I couldn't find any answers when searching for "where in do block scope", "where closure" or similar keywords. [This page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where) that compares `let` and `where` doesn't mention my case, the closest example I've found is the first bit of code from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lambda_lifting) where the "Lambda lifting" topic is covered. They're able to use `n` variable from outer scope within the function defined in `where`, but it's not in a `do` block as my case is.

So my question is - why exactly is `outerVar` variable not in scope of `doSomething`?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same issue. Thanks! I don't know why I couldn't find this question earlier...

Comment: Also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254124/difference-between-where-bindings-let-bindings-and-the-single-assignment-operat?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: (I reopened the question, then immediately realised it wasn't necessary to have done so. Sorry for the unnecessary pings!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`do` blocks are just syntactic sugar for chaining monadic values using `>>=` and lambda functions. Your block is first translated by the compiler into:

```
return "a" >>= \outerVar -> doSomething
  where doSomething =...
```

It should be obvious now that `outerVar` is not in scope outside the lambda to which it is an argument.

Comment: Thanks! That part of the explanation is missing in the answer to the question I accidentally duplicated. It makes it clearer now.