# Can someone explain to me or link me to a good guide that explains let and where in Haskell

Tags: haskell, where-clause, let

I have never used these two keywords in anything I have programmed because I don't really understand them or when they should be used, if they can be used together etc.

Comment: I recommend the Haskell 2010 Report.

Comment: @James http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362328/haskell-where-vs-let

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you have code like:

```
foo x y = if min (abs x) (abs y) > 0 then negate (min (abs x) (abs y)) else min (abs x) (abs y)
```

With `let` or `where`, you can introduce abbreviations for common expressions, which makes your code more readable:

```
foo x y = if z > 0 then negate z else z 
    where 
       z = min (abs x) (abs y)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
 foo x y = let
       z = min (abs x) (abs y)
    in if z > 0 then negate z else z
```

A let-expression is just that: an expression and can appear anywhere an expression can appear, while a `where` clause is the optional final part of a case alternative or pattern binding.

Comment: There are subtle differences, though.  [This](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Let_vs._Where) link explains it well as the last example where a slight change in how the function is defined can lead to a large difference in performance.