# Haskell Tail Recursive Inner Functions

Tags: haskell

Coming from a Scala background I'm pretty used to using tail recursion to write stuff that can't be easily represented using another method. Let's say I want to calculate the length of a list, but I don't want to use a fold. I want to do it in a natural tail recursive way. I thought of this way:

```
myLength :: [a]  -> Int
myLength x    = innerLength x 0

innerLength :: [a] -> Int -> Int  -- Tail recursive inner call
innerLength [] _      = 0
innerLength (x:xs) n  = innerLength xs n+1
```

and this works fine. But it isn't very readable that innerLength is really the tail recursive inner call to count the list members and it seems like innerLength is scoped in such a way someone could just use innerLength instead of the better myLength.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, use a `let` or `where` clause in the definition of `myLength`.

Comment: `innerLength xs n+1` is parsed as `(innerLength xs n)+1`, this is *not* tail-recursive.

Comment: What @Franky says, moreover `innerLength [] _ = 0` throws away the accumulator instead of returning it. It should be `innerLength [] n = n`. I'd also be tempted to use strict application in the recursive case e.g. `innerLength (_:xs) n = innerLength xs $! n+1`

Comment: @Franky Thanks for pointing that out. That seems to be a constant headache for me with haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can either use `let`:

```
myLength :: [a]  -> Int
myLength x = 
    let innerLength :: [a] -> Int -> Int  -- Tail recursive inner call
        innerLength [] n      = n
        innerLength (x:xs) n  = innerLength xs (n+1)
    in innerLength x 0
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f919c3a17ee2a58a)</kbd>

or `where`:

```
myLength :: [a]  -> Int
myLength x = innerLength x 0
    where innerLength :: [a] -> Int -> Int  -- Tail recursive inner call
          innerLength [] n      = n
          innerLength (x:xs) n  = innerLength xs (n+1)
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5243f5d172deaaf)</kbd>

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4362328/493122) for the difference between the two.

Comment: Well, `innerLength [] n = n`, really.

Comment: Haskell style often name the auxiliary function just "go" or "aux" since its scope is limited to the function and the alternative is just a repetition of the function name slightly modified, which doesn't bring any readability benefits. Only the top level functions usually get explicit signatures, it is considered that local variables are close enough to the potential problems that they don't need one (except if you wish to clarify a particularly obscure type).